# Convert template string to variable-reference

Tags: angularjs

I have an attribute-directive that looks like this:

```
directive('syncFocusWith', function($timeout, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            focusValue: "=syncFocusWith"
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch("focusValue", function(currentValue, previousValue) {

                console.log(previousValue);
                console.log(currentValue);
                if (currentValue === true && !previousValue) {
                    $element[0].focus();
                } else if (currentValue === false && previousValue) {
                    $element[0].blur();
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

If I set a value like this:

```
sync-focus-with="passwordfocus"
```

it works fine. Console.log will output the value of passwordfocus(that is set in a controller)

But I need to set a value like this:

```
sync-focus-with="method+'passwordfocus'"
```

(Method is passed from the parent directive like this):

```
<simperium-auth method="create"></simperium-auth>
```

If I set the value like that, angular treats it as a string, rather than a reference to an object in the scope. How can I make it reference an object in the scope?

Comment: jsfiddle would help ..

Answer (score 0):

After tearing my hair for hours, I realized how to do it just after I posted this:

```
        sync-focus-with="this[method+'usernamefocus']"
```

Is atleast one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing object notation like `this[method+'usernamefocus']` with your HTML it may not recommended. 
What I think you are looking for is `$scope.$eval`:

```
...
link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
var value = $scope.eval(attrs.syncFocusWith);
...
$scope.$watch(value
```